# PHP error validation with action

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am trying to create a simple form that gives the users an error on the same page if they do not put in a zip code. If they put in their zip code I want the form to go to another page. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php 

$errors = "";

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

if(0 === preg_match("/\S+/", $_GET['zip']))   
   $errors['zip'] = '<li type="square" >To proceed please enter a valid ZIP Code.</li>'; 
} else {
    die(header("Location: success.php"));
}   

?>

<?php

if ($errors != "") {   
    echo $errors['zip']; 
} 

?>    




<form name="zipcodeform" id="zipcodeform" action="" method="GET">
    <br />
    <h3>Try your self :</h3><br />

    <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top">Zip Code : </td>
            <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" value="<?php echo $_GET['zip']; ?>"  /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="submit"   id="submit"      value="Get Quotes >> " /></td>
        </tr>


</form>
```

Comment: Can you post your specific error?

Comment: Check whether `if(0 === preg_match("/\S+/", $_GET['zip']))` condition is working by simply echoing some content in if and else block. Also give some more details about what is happening in form.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things you should look for:

1. Is `$errors` a string or an array? If it is an array, you should initialize it properly.
2. Use stricter error_reporting (E_ALL). You will get a notice that `$_GET['plz']` isn't set when you open the page, without having submitted the form.
3. Always use `{}`. It's good coding style.

If you take all this into account the script should be running fine or at least you should see your mistakes. It runs fine at my place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Say your first (form.html) page is this

```
<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body>
 <form method='get' action='proceed.php'>
   Pin code : <input type='text' name='pincode'>
 <input type='Submit'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then your PHP page that deals with the form(proceed.php);

```
<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body>
<?PHP
  if($_GET['pincode']==''){
//Copy and paste the contents of body of 'form.html' with errors displayed!
   echo'<form method="get" action="proceed.php">
   Pin code : <input style="background:#FAA;" type="text" name="pincode">
   <li type="square" ><font color="red">To proceed please enter a valid ZIP Code.</font></li>
   <input type="Submit">';
  }
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors in your script. Try

```
<?php 

$errors = array();

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
  if( !preg_match("/\S+/", $_GET['zip']) ){
        $errors['zip'] = '<li type="square" >To proceed please enter a valid ZIP Code.</li>';
  } 

  if( !empty($errors) ){
      echo $errors['zip'];
  } else {
      header("Location: success.php");
      exit();
  }

} 

?>

<form name="zipcodeform" id="zipcodeform" action="" method="GET">
<br />
<h3>Try your self :</h3><br />

<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top">Zip Code : </td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['zip'])) echo $_GET['zip']; ?>"  /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="submit"  id="submit"   value="Get Quotes &gt;&gt;" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

Comment: There is an extra `>` in `value="Get Quotes >> "`

Comment: @Fred does it matter if its inside value? It will be displayed as a button text, right?

Comment: @AnkitPokhrel actually, there shouldn't be any `>>` in there. It should read as `value="Get Quotes"` - and yes, it does matter, because there is no PHP shorthand code inside the `td`.

Comment: @AnkitPokhrel Wait, scratch that.

Comment: @AnkitPokhrel In certain cases, depending on how the form will be displayed, it's always best to use `&gt;` symbols instead of `>`. I see what the OP wants to do now.

Comment: @Fred Oh, i didn't knew that. I thought it will not matter. I edited the answer

Comment: @AnkitPokhrel Again, depending on how a form or file is included, it could potentially cause problems. I always use `&gt;` and `&lt;` for `< >` symbols.

Comment: @AnkitPokhrel c.c Since I'm the only one that's noticed it, I've closed your table.